# Using * for file id in File.get to get all the files. results in error

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to use '*' as the wildcard in the fileid parameter in the Files.get request in the google api's explorer, for the google-drive api.

I want to get all the files in a folder, I have a list of the id's but need the files_get to pull the file_id's as well so they can match.

I've tried inputing a start at the fileid parameter but I keep getting the error file not found.

I have left a screenshot of my results below.

[screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOv4M.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## file.get

It looks like you are using the [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) method

> Gets **a** file's metadata or content by ID.

The key word in the above method from the documentation is that it gets **A** file you need to pass the file id.

## Fields

The parameters filed is used to for partial response. If you set it to name then only the name field will be returned in the response and the rest of the fields in the response will be null.

## file.list

You should be using [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) you can use page size to return a max of 1000 rows per page after that you will need to request the next page of data.

> pageSize   integer The maximum number of files to return per page. Partial or empty result pages are possible even before the end of the files list has been reached. Acceptable values are 1 to 1000, inclusive. (Default: 100)